# SQL - populate new column according to data in row above

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to populate a new column in a table known as RowType, where if the ID column contains the same ID value as the one above RowType is populated with 'D', if the value is new then RowType is populate with 'H', how would the SQL code look to be able to do this?

I.e should look something like below:

```
RowType (to be populated), ID (already there)
H, 1
D, 1
D, 1
H, 2
D, 2
H, 3
D, 3
D, 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: No timestamp or other unique column?

Comment: This Id is already there or you need to generate?

Comment: sorry, MS SQL, MySQL tag was in mistake. there are further columns that help to make the overall row unique to one another. i.e Row Type, ID, Range From, Range To

Comment: What you have tried and whats error on that?

Comment: H, 1, 10am, 11am, then next row - D, 1, 11am, 12pm, and then next row - H, 2, 10am, 12pm etc...

Comment: @Kannan Kandasamy I'm not really sure where to begin so would appreciate some guidance

Comment: I think you can insert your table into temp table with additional row_number() over column represents row_number, then loop this table with comparing current row ID value with previous row ID value, if the same then update RowType to D else update to H.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that there will be more than the three values of ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_Number and case

```
select *, RowType = case when Row_Number() over (partition by id order by id) = 1 then 'H' else 'D' End from #yourid
```

Your input table:

```
create table #yourId (id int)

insert into #yourid (id) values
 (1)
,(1)
,(1)
,(2)
,(2)
,(3)
,(3)
,(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMER concept :

```
CREATE TABLE #table(Id INT)

INSERT INTO #table(Id)
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3

SELECT CASE WHEN RowType = 1 THEN 'H' ELSE 'D' END RowType , Id
FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY id) RowType , Id
   FROM #table
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try...

```
UPDATE tableName
SET RowType = CASE
                  WHEN ( ID = LAG( ID ) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) ) THEN 'D'
                  ELSE 'H'
              END
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql (for information on `LAG()`).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, however it can point you somewhere, and it works. 
Go through the code carfuly and make sure you understand this.

```
create table yourTable (RowType char, id int)

insert into yourTable (RowType, id) values
 ('',1)
,('',1)
,('',1)
,('',2)
,('',2)
,('',3)
,('',3)
,('',3)

select 
    row_number() over (order by id) as rowNumber,
    RowType,
    id
into #tempTable
from yourTable

declare @maxRow int = (select max(rowNumber) from #tempTable)
declare @currentRow int = 1
while (@currentRow <= @maxRow)
begin
    if (@currentRow = 1)
    begin
        update #tempTable
        set RowType = 'H'
        where rowNumber = @currentRow
    end
    else
    begin
        if (select id from #tempTable where rowNumber = @currentRow) = (select id from #tempTable where rowNumber = @currentRow - 1)
        begin
            update #tempTable
            set RowType = 'D'
            where rowNumber = @currentRow
        end
        else 
        begin
            update #tempTable
            set RowType = 'H'
            where rowNumber = @currentRow
        end
    end
    set @currentRow = @currentRow +1
end

-- update data in actual table, you can do below if only those two columns exist in table !!!
delete from yourTable

-- insert into table from updated temp table
insert into yourTable
select RowType, ID
from #tempTable

select * from yourTable

select * from #tempTable

-- drop temp table
drop table #tempTable
```